# I’m trying to make a digital "receipt" using the props that are in a class and using a counter that tells me the quantity, multiply it by the price,

Tags: reactjs

I state that I am a novice with React

I've tried to do so...but it doesn't work

these are the constant that i've created:

```
const [Receipt,setReceipt]=useState(0);
  //here i try to take the value on another class
  const quantity = {...this.props.cards};
  const price= {...this.props.cards};
```

This is the button that should calculate the receipt

```
  return( 
//This is the button that i use to do the Receipt
<div>
      <p>  {Receipt} </p>
      
      <button onClick={() => setReceipt(this.quantity * this.prezzo)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>

  );

  
}
}
```

Comment: So whats the issue? From what i can see you're using hooks in a class component.
but still it'd be helpful if you tell us what errors you're encountering

Comment: this is the error:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class based component. This means that you cannot use hooks like "useState". Hooks are only meant for functional components.

If you want to use state in your class components, you need to do it the class based way.

Which is like this :

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {receipt: 0};
  }
```

In your html you can then do something like :

```
<div>
      <p>  {this.state.receipt} </p>
      
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({receipt: this.quantity * this.prezzo })}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I've tried as you say...but still doesn't work :(
The console on the webpage gives me this error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'props')